# Properties of a single-message protocol using AES

Tags: aes, protocol-analysis

The following protocol is used for providing data confidentiality between sender and receiver:

$$ \text{sender} \rightarrow \text{receiver}: E_k(m \mathbin\Vert \mathrm{ID}_s\mathbin\Vert \mathrm{Timestamp}) $$

- $E_k$: the encryption function of AES
- $k$: a shared secret key
- $\mathrm{ID}_s$: the ID of sender
- $\mathrm{Timestamp}$: the time
- $m$: the message (payload) from the sender

Assume that AES is secure. What are the security services that can be provided by this protocol?

I think we can get the Sender authentication because of the sender ID. But how about the others like data integrity, non-repudiation or data authentication? Can AES and this protocol provide this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Non repudiation :** No, as the sender can claim that the other person sent himself the message 
**Data Integrity :** No, as the cipher text can be corrupted in the midway
**Authentication :** Yes, the message is indeed sent by other sender as the key is known only to sender and receiver 
**Confidentiality:** Yes, as the key is only known to receiver and sender

Hope this helps

Comment: May I ask any other services that would be involved in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: @Ng Clement, can you be bit more specific about what type of services?

Comment: like the Confidentiality, integrity and availability (CIA)?

Comment: Edited the answer for confidentiality, can't say anything about availability as it depends upon the two parties and not on the algorithm in specific.

Comment: One more question. Are there any other security services that you know  we need to consider?

Comment: If we go deep into the AES, it is resistant to linear and differential attacks however it was prone to side channel attack but with the recent hardware support AES became perfectly secure.

Comment: Would you mind to briefly describe linear and differential attacks? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by authentication because messages can be replayed.

Comment: @Elias, as the encrypted message includes Timestamp it can't be replayed.

Comment: The protocol does not provide authentication. It is possible to forge a ciphertext with a different payload and different timestamp. How easy it is depends on what Ek is. To protect against forgeries, the protocol would need to use use authenticated encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the protocol is not correct: the encryption function of AES can only encrypt a message of exactly 16 bytes (the block size). Evidently here you need to encrypt a variable-length message, so $E_k$ should instead be some [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) of AES.

Assuming that $E_k$ is an encryption mode of AES, such as AES-CBC or AES-CTR, the protocol obviously ensures the confidentiality of the payload $m$, since it's only ever sent in encrypted form with a key that remains confidential.

The protocol does not guarantee integrity, authenticity or non-repudiation since it is possible to forge a ciphertext without knowing the key. The forger may not be able to know exactly what is in the fake $m$ that they're sending, but a forgery is feasible. How easy it is depends on the [malleability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)) of the encryption algorithm. Taking AES-CTR as an example, you can flip any bit in the ciphertext, and this decrypts to the corresponding plaintext with the same bit flipped. So if an adversary sees a ciphertext, they can send a modified message with a different payload, ID or timestamp with precise control over how the message is modified. AES-CBC is less malleable (to oversimplify, if the adversary modifies the ciphertext at some point, then the following block will decrypt into garbage), but can be corrupted nonetheless, so there is no guarantee of authenticity.

If $E_k$ is an **[authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption)** mode of AES, such as AES-GCM or AES-CCM, then the protocol does guarantee the authenticity of the payload $m$, since the transmitted message includes an authentication tag that covers the combination of the payload $m$ with the 
sender's identity $\mathrm{ID}_s$. (Note that this would not be the case if the message was $E_k(m)||E_k(\mathrm{ID}_s)||E_k(\mathrm{Timestamp})$, since an attacker could listen to multiple communications and combine different pieces together.)

The protocol does not provide any integrity guarantee since an adversary can suppress messages in transit and can replay old messages. The timestamp does not help with integrity since there is nothing wrong with an old message in itself: how old a legitimate message is depends on the speed of the transmission. To detect message repetition, the recipient could save a log of received timestamps; this can only work if the sender never sends multiple messages with the same timestamp, which either means a very high resolution timestamp and a high clock refresh rate on the sender, or use a counter instead of a timestamp. Using a counter also allows the receiver to detect message losses.

Since the key is shared between the sender and the receiver, there is no non-repudiation property: the receiver can forge any message, so the sender can repudiate a message by claiming the receiver made it.